# Question regarding definition of Lebesgue integral

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am reading *Measure Theory* by Halmos, and I was wondering if someone could help me on the following definition:

If there exists a mean fundamental sequence $\left\{f_{n}\right\}$ of integrable simple functions which converges in measure to an a.e. finite valued, measurable function $f$ on a measure space $(X, \mathbf{S}, \mu).$ Then the $\int f d \mu=\lim _{n} \int f_{n} d \mu$ is defined as the integral of f.

A sequence {fn}is mean fundamental sequence if $\int |f_n-f_m| \rightarrow 0$ as n,m goes to infinity. It Converge in measure to f if for each epsilon,  $\mu (\{ x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|> \epsilon \}) \rightarrow 0$ as n goes to inifinity.

I understand that it is the definition, but I was wondering why does $\lim _{n} \int f_{n} d \mu$ exists in the first place(why does this limit exist)?

Comment: The definition of Lebesgue integral is first defined for measurable non-negative functions. In this case, the limit is allowed to be infinite.

Comment: I don't know if this is the case, but you should check it.

Comment: What's the definition of a mean fundamental sequence?

Comment: Another more modern name for a mean fundamental sequence would be mean Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @yi G what's a mean fundamental (Cauchy-) sequence? You should give a definition in your question, so we can help.

Comment: Alright, I added the definition!

Comment: From $$\Biggl\lvert \int f_n - \int f_m\Biggr\rvert \leqslant \int \lvert f_n - f_m\rvert$$ it follows that the sequence of integrals is a Cauchy sequence.